# Передать в ссылку переменную из javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите плз, есть скрипт получающий значение (и для проверки выводящей его в консоль) и кнопка на которой висит значение при клике перейти по ссылке. Требуется передать переменную в ссылку:

```
<script> function qty() {
 var q = document.getElementById('qty').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
console.log(q);
}
</script>
```

Кнопка следом:

`<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/cart/create?id=2&q='ВОТ ТУТ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ" class="qwe"></button>`

суть в том, чтобы человек при нажатии на спиннер (и увеличении этим числа, которое попадет в переменную) и последующем нажатии на кнопку button передал на контроллер количество (коим является переменная q).

Comment: `location.href='/cart/create?id=2&q='+qty()`, и `return q;` в функции не забыть...

Comment: огромное спасибо! в вариантах,что я пробовал,я заретурнить результат  забыл.. потому и не работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.href='/cart/create?id=2&q='+qty()`, и `return q;` в функции не забыть..

Comment: Вы просто скопировали комментарий, но комментарий и существует для краткости. Ответ же ожидается более развёрнутый. Дополните  ответ, как вам это помогло в решении вашего вопроса.